# Does the system persist state information for dynamically added fragments when the layout changes?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm writing an app and some of the fragments need to be dynamically added and thus not defined in a layout file.

What I have is two main_activity.xml files, one in layout and one in layout-land. But I'm trying to populate them dynamically from a single MainActivity.java file without much success. I can get it to create the fragments and show the layouts but I can't get it to persist the data across 'configuration changes' - ie to show the same data in an edittext when the orientation changes.

The fragments used in both layouts are the same but the container ids in the layout files are different (ie I add '_wide' to the layout-land versions). Is this relevant? Do they have to be the same for the system to 'remember' them?

I get fragments in theory but I just keep running into a brick wall when trying to implement them. All I want to do is be able to add x number of instances of the same fragment at runtime (into a linearlayout container) but at the same time let the system take care of maintaining the state information. Is it possible or am I missing something fundamental about how all this works?

Comment: If you are using different ids, you have to specifically handle it in your source code.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your reply. I don't suppose you can suggest any questions on here that give good examples of how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

use the below line in your manifest file

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
```

like

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.demo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Let me know is it useful or not ?

Comment: Normally, on ConfigChanged, activity life-cycle starts again from oncreate. So use the line android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" to prevent it.

Comment: Just bear with me I need to play around with it a bit - the rest of my code might need some work. I'll let you know :-)

Comment: It's working for one layout but it's not switching to the other. It's also persisting across installs on my test phone from Eclipse - which I've never seen happen before. My fragment instantiation code is in onCreate - should it be elsewhere?

Comment: Good, you have got the solution by your own answer (Below one), right?
Just clarify me , are you using android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" in your own answer ?. Actually i do not have 50 reputations to add comment on your answer.

Comment: Hi again. My solution doesn't use android:configChanges or onConfigurationChanged. I couldn't get them to work - which is no reflection on you or your answer by the way... I'm just not that advanced an android programmer yet. My 'solution' is nothing new - it's probably how everybody does it - but I just needed the clarification in my own mind.

Answer (score 0):

Got there in the end. So the answer to my original question is yes, the system does remember state information for fragments dynamically added - if you do it right.

Doing it right means:
a) Use layout files with the same name in different 'resource buckets' eg main_activity.xml in 'layout', layout-land, and wherever else.
b) Ensure that all container ids for a given fragment (or fragments) are the same across all the various layout files. In other words a fragment can only be associated with one container id but that id can appear in many layout files. I have found that only the id itself has to be the same - the type of viewgroup used as a container can be different across the layout files as can anything else not related to the fragments.
c) In the onCreate method you only need to instantiate the fragments and add them (via a fragment transaction) to their container once (ie if savedinstancestate == null). You can create your entire UI dynamically this way - including using arrays of fragments - and the system remembers all the state information for every fragment, applying it to the next layout file it uses.

I'm sorry if this was all blatantly obvious to everyone, but I needed the clarification.